# Maven - Unresolved references to [javax.activation, javax.annotation]

Tags: java, plugins, maven, pom.xml, apache-felix

I'm developing web application with OSGI. I have a maven configuration error which I cannot find. This is the complete source code:
http://uploading.com/files/8e5c9888/SH_27_test.zip/

This is the POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27</groupId>
        <artifactId>SH_27</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>SH_27-impl</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>SH_27-impl</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>SH_27-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>SH_27-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>${pom.groupId}.api, org.osgi.framework</Import-Package>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Activator>${pom.groupId}.impl.SessionHandleApp</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>org.DX_57.osgi.SH_27</groupId>
</project>
```

When I try to compile it with Netbeans I get this error:
http://pastebin.com/whxuSb7V

The problem occurs when I add @Datasource. It seems that I'm missing something in the POM file but I don't have idea what it is?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best Wishes 
Peter

Comment: You need to include something that has the JEE classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
 <Import-Package>${pom.groupId}.api, org.osgi.framework</Import-Package>
```

Should be:

```
 <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
```

I hope that this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Maven: Unresolved references to [org.osgi.service.http]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2529226/827480).  I think he had the same problem that he managed to resolve by including specific packages that need to be imported.

Comment: It's still not working. I tested the suggested corrections in the post but I get the same error.